# how to read Blank cells AS String from Excel File Using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am new to Apache POI. I want to Read the blank cells as well. 
This is what I tried to achieve my objective but it problem is that it doesn't continue reading after getting a blank cell.

*here is my logic*

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFRow row;
            HSSFCell cell = null;
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
             while (rows.hasNext()) {


                    row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                     if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                            continue;
                    } 
                    Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                    while(cells.hasNext()){
                        HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
               if(myCell.getCellType()!=Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                           myCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

                       }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Blank cells are not returned in iterators. Quoting [Poi's quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator):

> Note that a rowIterator and cellIterator iterate over rows or cells that have been created, skipping empty rows and cells.

Another option is to iterate through each cell with

```
row.getCell(i)
```

and check if null or its type is Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK

You can get the last and first row numbers from Sheet's methods

```
sheet.getFirstRowNum()
sheet.getLastRowNum()
```

Same for first and last column using row's methods

```
row.getFirstCellNum()
row.getLastCellNum()
```

Comment: Not Even Getting See.                                                                     
 for(int j=sheet.getFirstRowNum();j<=sheet.getLastRowNum();j++){
                        
                        for(int k=row.getFirstCellNum();k<=row.getLastCellNum();k++){
                            
                           System.out.println(cell.getCellType());
                                
                        }
                    }

Comment: Inside that loop you need to getCell(k). That cell can be null, if not null, check if its type is Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK

Comment: but its also should be print the null type (int code)..i m not getting too

Comment: Can you post your complete code. In the code of your comment you are not updating cell reference.